# Locking a second drop down field after first drop down choice is made

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have this code where when drop down one is chosen, it automatically populates drop down two. I would like to lock this drop down 'two' where it can not be manually edited. Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/54/

```
var objArray = {"On-Call Service": "Per Pickup", 
"Every Six Months (2 Stops Annually)": "Per Pickup", 
"Every Three Months (4 Stops Annually)": "Every  Three Months", 
"Every Other Month (6 Stops Annually)": "Every Other Month",  
"Monthly (12-13 Stops Annually)": "Per Month", 
"Every Other Week (26 Stops  Annually)": "Per Month", 
"Every Week (52 Stops Annually)": "Per Month"};

$("#00NA00000047Jk8").change(function()
{
var ddText = $(this).val();
$.each(objArray,function(key,value)
{
    if(ddText == key)
        $("#00NA0000005wIiU").val(value);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `prop('disabled', true)` it will disable the dropdown so one can not change is manually.

check below code.

```
$("#00NA00000047Jk8").change(function()
{
    var ddText = $(this).val();

    $.each(objArray,function(key,value)
    {
        if(ddText == key)
            $("#00NA0000005wIiU").val(value);
            $("#00NA0000005wIiU").prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

it might help you.

Comment: That kinda works...  http://jsfiddle.net/k4hYE/55/    but it disables drop down one vs. drop down two i.e.00NA0000005wIiU

Comment: @user3498478 : okay, my mistake. check updated answer.